# How "execute_script" works in Selenium ? Injection of code directly in the page or not?

Tags: python, selenium

I need that `execute_script` doesn't inject js code directly in the source code of the page.
I believe it's the case because when I check with CTRL+F in DEV TOOLS of chrome, I can't find my js code.

But, I would like to know how `execute_script` exactly works (I already searched a couple of hours...)

Thanks and have agood day !

Comment: You need to check Webdriver Protocol https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#execute-script . Answer to your question is yes.

Comment: @RahulL Thanks, do you think that the website I was scrapping can detect my js code ?

Comment: Yes . Most modern site implements bot detections mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply executes js code on the client side. Here are some few examples with `execute_script` https://www.guru99.com/execute-javascript-selenium-webdriver.html

Comment: OK, thanks. But how exactly my js code is executed on the client side ? Is it injected in the source code (I believe no) ? Or another technique ?

Comment: It is executed as you do it in the console on the website

Comment: OK thanks. With console.log() I just found my js code in the console of Chrome. My js code is located here : "debugger:///VM95:25" (from the console). Do you think that the website I was scrapping can detect my js code ?